# Valid palindrome solution

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, palindrome

I'm working on this valid palindrome problem. Any advice on code bug, better idea for low algorithm execution time complexity, code style, etc. are highly appreciated.

> **Problem**
>
> Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only
>   alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.
>
> Example
>
> "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" is a palindrome. "race a car" is not
>   a palindrome.
>
> Note
>
> Have you consider that the string might be empty? This is a good
>   question to ask during an interview. For the purpose of this problem,
>   we define empty string as valid palindrome.

**Source Code**

```
def check_valid(source):
    i = 0
    j = len(source)-1
    source =source.lower()
    while i <= j:
        while i<=j and not ('a'<=source[i]<='z'):
            i+=1
        while i<=j and not ('a'<=source[j]<='z'):
            j-=1
        if i<=j:
            if source[i] != source[j]:
                return False
            else:
                i+=1
                j-=1
        if i > j:
            return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print check_valid('A man, a plan, a canal: Panama') # return True
    print check_valid('race a car') # return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Some small nitpicks:

1. Instead of `i <= j` you can stop before `j` by doing: `i < j` in the last two `while` loops. That way, you'll save one iteration per `while`. If you weren't constraint by: "*For the purpose of this problem, we define empty string as valid palindrome*" you might've remove that as well
2. Here: `('a'<=source[i]<='z')` you can remove the redundant parentheses and also write it like: `source[i].isalnum()`
3. It seems like you always forget to put a <kbd>space</kbd> between operators: `i+=1` should be `i += 1`.
4. Add docstrings to your function

#### Reviewed code:

```
def check_valid(source):
    """ Return True/False if a string is a palindrome """

    i, j, source = 0, len(source) - 1, source.lower()
    while i <= j:
        while i < j and not source[i].isalnum():
            i += 1
        while i < j and not source[j].isalnum():
            j -= 1
        if i <= j:
            if source[i] != source[j]:
                return False
            else:
                i += 1
                j -= 1
        if i > j:
            return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print check_valid('A man, a plan, a canal: Panama')  # return True
    print check_valid('race a car')  # return False
```

Answer (score 4):

The pythonic way to check for a palindrome is using `s[::-1] == s`, i.e. a negative step for the slice operator.

With your additional constraints your code could be:

```
def check_valid(source):
    l = [c.lower() for c in source if c.isalnum()]
    return l[::-1] == l
```

Note that this uses an additional O(2m) memory, because it copies the string effectively twice (once to form the list with m alphanumeric characters out of the n characters in the input string and another when reversing it).